# take sum of all members of groupBy in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I using groupBy week to get result from database before that i am usin `WithSum()` to take sum of relation table column . it is working fine but it is only taking sum of first member of groupBy for example if there are 20 member it will only show the sum of first member

```
 Consignment::Select(DB::raw('week(created_at) as created_at_week'))->withSum('charges','income')->when($request->customer_id, function ($q) use ($request) {
      return $q->where('customer_id', $request->customer_id);
    })->groupBy('created_at_week')->get();
```

How I can take sum of all consignments in each groupBy week?

Comment: are `members` and `customers` the same? if so, you are only filtering a specific customer in your closure!

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple columns in group by clause

```
 Consignment::Select(DB::raw('week(created_at) as created_at_week'))->withSum('charges','income')->when($request->customer_id, function ($q) use ($request) {
  return $q->where('customer_id', $request->customer_id);
})->groupBy(['created_at_week','MEMBER_ID_COLUMN'])->get();
```